# Compile Errors vs. Runtime errors

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime

I understand the difference between a compiler error and a runtime error and what examples are for each of them. My question is, computationally speaking, which is better? Does a statically typed language that catches an error at compile time save any more space or increase efficiency for the computer than a dynamically typed language that catches errors at run time?

Comment: It's not about saving space or time - it's about fixing more errors while your code is safely only on your system, rather than those errors affecting users. Statically typed languages have historically been more efficient than dynamically typed languages as well, because more can be worked out at compile-time, but a) the performance of dynamically typed languages has come a long way; b) that performance isn't really about errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Compiler errors get detected by compiler at the time of code development.
>
> Runtime time errors are not get detected by compiler and hence identified at the time of code execution.

asking which is better is irrelevant =)